# Бесконечная загрузка pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin4, pgadmin

Недавно пришлось переустановить PostgreSQL на своем компьютере. Теперь при попытке открыть pgAdmin4 открывается его страница, на которой не прекращается загрузка, хотя до переустановки такого не было. Пробовал установить pgAdmin4 отдельно от PostgreSQL, но ничего не изменилось. Может кто-нибудь уже сталкивался с такой проблемой?[image: Загрузочный экран pgAdmin4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. Переустанавливал весь PostgreSQL много раз, но pgAdmin4 отказывался загружаться. У меня он был версии v4.28.

В итоге скачал отдельно недавно вышедшую версию pgAdmin4 v4.30 [вот отсюда](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.30/).
Там необходимо только выбрать соответствующую папку для вашей системы. Теперь pgAdmin4 наконец-то запускается и работает.